# CakePHP preserving validation errors after redirecting

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have an element which displays a comment form, the action is comments/add.  If the form doesn't validate, I don't want users to go to comments/add (the view for which does not exist), but I want them to remain on the same page and see the validation errors there.

However, redirecting to $this->referer() doesn't work - the validation errors disappear and just the flash message remains.

```
public function add(){
    if (!empty($this->data)){
        $this->Comment->create();
        if ($this->Comment->save($this->data)){
            $this->Session->setFlash('Comment added.','success');
            $this->redirect($this->referer());
        }else{
            $this->Session->setFlash('There was a problem adding your comment.  Please try again.','failure');
        }
    }
}
```

How can I either retain the validation errors and form data on redirect?  If this isn't possible, how else can I solve the problem?

Thanks a lot,

Will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/binarycrafts/2010/01/20/persistentvalidation-keeping-your-validation-data-after-redirects-2

Comment: Thanks, it works.  For anyone interested, I had to add Comment to the $uses array of BlogsController.  Then it just works out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove $this->redirect($this->referer()); altogether.

Also, if you have your field validations set up properly, how is the user even getting to the redirect? the save() function should fail if invalid data is entered and the user will never see the redirect and the db will never accept any data.

Comment: Sorry, I copied the code wrong: $this->redirect($this->referer()); is after the if/else statement.  Removing that line just makes Cake attempt to show the view for comments/add, which like I said doesn't exist.