# CakePHP - Errorhandling form in separate view element

Tags: php, forms, cakephp

Just starting out playing with CakePHP so please bear with me if this is an easy question.

I'm using CakePHP 2.4.0 and I want to reuse a specific form in multiple views. Therefore, I add this form to an view-element and include this element in each view.

This is the element.ctp file:

```
<?php

echo $this->Form->create('Lead', array('type' => 'post',
                                       'url'  => array('controller' => 'Lead', 'action' => 'index'),
                                       'novalidate'   => true));

echo $this->Form->input('name', array('label' => 'Achternaam'));
echo $this->Form->input('email', array('label' => 'Email'));
echo $this->Form->input('phone', array('label' => 'Telefoon'));
echo $this->Form->submit('submit', array('name'  => 'submit'));    
?>
```

This element is included in multiple views in the following way:

This is the home.ctp (a view) file:

```
<?php echo $this->element('element'); ?>
```

This is the LeadController.php file that receives the post operation from the form:

```
<?php
class LeadController extends AppController{

    public function index(){
        $this->autoRender = false;
        if(!empty($_POST))
           $this->Lead->save($this->request->data);
        $this->redirect('/Pages/home');
    }
}
?>
```

This is the Lead.php file that hodls all the validation checks.

```
class Lead extends AppModel{

public $useTable = 'Leads';

public $validate = array(
    'email' => array(
        'required' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'required' => true,
            'message' => 'need email'
        ),
        'validEmailRule' => array(
            'rule' => array('email'),
            'required' => true,
            'message' => 'invalid emial'
        )
    ),
    'name' => array(
        'required' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'required' => true,
            'message' => 'need name'
        )
    ),....
```

When the form in the view-element is completely valid, than the data from the form is successfully added to the database. But when the form is invalid, than the errors aren't returned to the view. If I write the following in the LeadController to the logfile than they are shown their.

```
$this->Lead->invalidFields();
```

If I add the code from LeadController/index to PagesController/home and change the form submit url, than the errors are shown in the view at each form-element.

What do you have to do to show the errors from a form in the view at each form-element, when the form is placed in a separate view-element and reused in multiple pages?

This has probably something to do with the fact that I use a redirect but I think their is a better way than saving the errors  temporarily in a session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This has probably something to do with the fact that I use a
>   redirect...

It's actually COMPLETELY to do with the fact that you use a redirect.  By redirecting, you lose the validation errors.

There are as many ways to deal with this as your imagination can think of (and each has it's own merits depending on YOUR situation), but it is already widely asked/answered on the web:

[CakePHP preserving validation errors after redirecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235765/cakephp-preserving-validation-errors-after-redirecting)

http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/binarycrafts/2010/01/20/persistentvalidation-keeping-your-validation-data-after-redirects-2

[CakePHP: Keep validation data upon redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553192/cakephp-keep-validation-data-upon-redirect)

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cake-php/NsfckwSfY5c

Comment: Thank you for these links. You can use: $this->render('/Pages/home'); instead of redirecting in the leadcontroller. This way it works without doing additional work.